# What are the differences between substr method and slice method in this exercise?

Tags: javascript, string, methods

I'm currently going through method exercises for myself and came across two different ones that function a bit similar to each other. However, even though the first parameter of both is the starting index of the string, the second parameters throw me off and confuse me.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
var newStringMethod = 'lets try a subslice method on this string primitive data type variable';
```

That is my string variable I created for myself on this exercise.

I started with a substr method for this variable....

```
var subSlice = newStringMethod.substr(7, 10);
```

After calling subSlice, this was returned as my value.

```
"y a subsli"
```

I moved on to a slice method.

```
var reguarSlice = newStringMethod.slice(7, 10);
```

Once I called it, I was returned with this as a value.

```
"y a"
```

All I'm doing to understand this whole thing is just simply count each individual letter, starting from 0. Just from using that to understand them is a clear indication I need some further explanation on these two methods. What are the distinguishable attributes and functions in the second parameters of each of these two string methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware that `.slice(7, 10)` method will return letters starting from `7` index up to `10` index (excluding the letter on with `10th` index).

```js
var newStringMethod = 'lets try a subslice method on this string primitive data type variable';
console.log(newStringMethod.slice(7, 10));
```

`.substr(7, 10)` method will return **10** letters, starting from `7` index.

```js
var newStringMethod = 'lets try a subslice method on this string primitive data type variable';
console.log(newStringMethod.substr(7, 10));
```

If you are looking for the same result, use `.substring` function instead, which will return the same result as `slice`.

```js
var newStringMethod = 'lets try a subslice method on this string primitive data type variable';
console.log(newStringMethod.substring(7, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

The distinguishable attributes of these two methods are:

`substr` will output the next 10 characters from the 7th character in the string. This is a more visual example of what it is doing:

> 'lets tr(y)`<- 7th index` a subsl(i)`<-10th index from 7th`ce method on this string primitive data type variable'

`slice` will simply output the 7th character to the 10th (7 - 10) character including spaces. This is a more visual example of what slice is doing.

> lets tr(y a)`<- 7th to 10th index` subslice method on this string primitive data type variable

Answer (score 0):

**[String#substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) syntax:**

```
str.substr(startIndex, length)
```

`substr()` method returns specified number of characters(`length`) from a string beginning at `startIndex`.

*For example:*

```
var newStringMethod = 'lets try a subslice method on this string primitive data type variable';
//                            ----------
//                            start at index 7 and return 10 characters
var subSlice = newStringMethod.substr(7, 10);
// returns "y a subsli"
```

**[String#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) syntax:**

```
str.slice(beginIndex[, endIndex])
```

`slice()` method extracts a section of string from `beginIndex` to `endIndex`. If `endIndex` is not specified then it would extract section of string from `beginIndex` to end of string. Also, note that character at `endIndex` will not be included in result.

*For example:*

```
var newStringMethod = 'lets try a subslice method on this string primitive data type variable';
//                            ---
//                            start at index 7 and ends at index 10 excluding value at endIndex 10
var reguarSlice = newStringMethod.slice(7, 10);
// returns "y a"
```